# Trying to figure out unexplained error with JUnit tests and model object

Tags: java, spring, database, oop, jdbctemplate

I am working on modeling several java objects that manage entities in a mySQL database using the JDBCTemplate.

I have run Add/Get JUnit tests on two other objects and I am not getting any errors, but I cannot figure out what is causing this error for my 'Organization' object.

**Here is my 'Organization' dto code:**

```
package com.sg.superherosightings.model;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Organization {
    
    private int orgId;
    private String orgName;
    private String orgDescription;
    private String orgPhone;
    private String orgEmail;
    private String orgStreetAddress;
    private String orgCity;
    private String orgState;
    private String orgZipCode;

    
    
    public int getOrgId() {
        return orgId;
    }

    public void setOrgId(int orgId) {
        this.orgId = orgId;
    }

    public String getOrgName() {
        return orgName;
    }

    public void setOrgName(String orgName) {
        this.orgName = orgName;
    }

    public String getOrgDescription() {
        return orgDescription;
    }

    public void setOrgDescription(String orgDescription) {
        this.orgDescription = orgDescription;
    }

    public String getOrgPhone() {
        return orgPhone;
    }

    public void setOrgPhone(String orgPhone) {
        this.orgPhone = orgPhone;
    }

    public String getOrgEmail() {
        return orgEmail;
    }

    public void setOrgEmail(String orgEmail) {
        this.orgEmail = orgEmail;
    }

    public String getOrgStreetAddress() {
        return orgStreetAddress;
    }

    public void setOrgStreetAddress(String orgStreetAddress) {
        this.orgStreetAddress = orgStreetAddress;
    }

    public String getOrgCity() {
        return orgCity;
    }

    public void setOrgCity(String orgCity) {
        this.orgCity = orgCity;
    }

    public String getOrgState() {
        return orgState;
    }

    public void setOrgState(String orgState) {
        this.orgState = orgState;
    }

    public String getOrgZipCode() {
        return orgZipCode;
    }

    public void setOrgZipCode(String orgZipCode) {
        this.orgZipCode = orgZipCode;
    }

    
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.orgId;
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgName);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgDescription);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgPhone);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgEmail);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgStreetAddress);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgCity);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgState);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgZipCode);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Organization other = (Organization) obj;
        if (this.orgId != other.orgId) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgName, other.orgName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgDescription, other.orgDescription)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgPhone, other.orgPhone)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgEmail, other.orgEmail)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgStreetAddress, other.orgStreetAddress)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgCity, other.orgCity)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgState, other.orgState)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgZipCode, other.orgZipCode)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

   

   
    
    
}
```

**Here is my Mapper Method in my DaoDBImpl:**
[img of OrgMapper Method before fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgQC3.png)

**This is my SuperSightings_DaoTest method causing the error:**

```
package com.sg.superherosightings.dao;

import com.sg.superherosightings.model.Location;
import com.sg.superherosightings.model.Organization;
import com.sg.superherosightings.model.Power;
import com.sg.superherosightings.model.Sighting;
import com.sg.superherosightings.model.Supe;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class SuperSightings_DaoTest {
    
    SuperSightings_Dao dao;
    
    public SuperSightings_DaoTest() {
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ApplicationContext ctx
        = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-applicationContext.xml");
            
            dao = ctx.getBean("SuperSightings_Dao", SuperSightings_Dao.class);
            
            // delete all supes
            List<Supe> supes = dao.getAllSupes(); for (Supe currentSupe : supes) {
            dao.deleteSupe(currentSupe.getSupeId()); 
            }
            // delete all powers
            List<Power> powers = dao.getAllPowers(); for (Power currentPower : powers) {
            dao.deletePower(currentPower.getPowerId()); 
            }
            //delete all organizations
            List<Organization> orgs = dao.getAllOrganizations(); for (Organization currentOrg : orgs) {
            dao.deleteOrganization(currentOrg.getOrgId()); 
            }
            // delete all locations
            List<Location> locations = dao.getAllLocations(); for (Location currentLocation : locations) {
            dao.deleteLocation(currentLocation.getLocationId()); 
            }
            // delete all sightings
            List<Sighting> sightings = dao.getAllSightings(); for (Sighting currentSighting : sightings) {
            dao.deleteSighting(currentSighting.getSightingId()); 
            }
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of addPower method, of class SuperSightings_Dao.
     */
    @Test
    public void testAddGetPower() {
        Power power = new Power();
        power.setPowerType("Fire");
        power.setPowerDescription("Shoots fire from hands");
        
        
        dao.addPower(power);
        
        Power fromDao = dao.getPowerById(power.getPowerId());
        assertEquals(fromDao, power);
       
    }

   
    /**
     * Test of deletePower method, of class SuperSightings_Dao.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDeletePower() {
        Power power = new Power();
        power.setPowerType("Fire");
        power.setPowerDescription("Shoots fire from hands");
        
        
        dao.addPower(power);
        
        Power fromDao = dao.getPowerById(power.getPowerId());
        assertEquals(fromDao, power);
        
        dao.deletePower(power.getPowerId());
        assertNull(dao.getPowerById(power.getPowerId()));
        
    }


    /**
     * Test of getAllPowersBySupeId method, of class SuperSightings_Dao.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetAllPowersBySupeId() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of addOrganization method, of class SuperSightings_Dao.
     */
    @Test
    public void testAddGetOrganization() {
    
        Organization org = new Organization();
        org.setOrgName("Legion of Doom");
        org.setOrgDescription("evil organization");
        org.setOrgPhone("333-444-5678");
        org.setOrgEmail("lod@evil.org");
        org.setOrgStreetAddress("344 Lowland Blvd.");
        org.setOrgCity("Quahog");
        org.setOrgState("RI");
        org.setOrgZipCode("09678");
        
        dao.addOrganization(org);
        
        Organization fromDao = dao.getOrganizationById(org.getOrgId());
        assertEquals(fromDao, org); //this is the line causing the error
    
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

> testAddGetOrganization(com.sg.superherosightings.dao.SuperSightings_DaoTest)
> Time elapsed: 0.107 sec  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.AssertionError:
> expected:com.sg.superherosightings.model.Organization@ae511546 but
> was:com.sg.superherosightings.model.Organization@15fabf0f

Please let me know if I need to provide further information. i am trying to get better at how i post questions here. I searched for a long time before asking but all I can find is that it might be something with my equals/hash code. I'm just not sure what is getting changed when the comparison is made because it is not happening with my other objects.

Thank you for any hints, and please don't bite my head off!

Comment: Where is dao declared?

Comment: You can add toString() method in which you will concat all field values, and before assertEquals print these two Organization classes on console and you will see differences

Comment: The dao is declared at the top of my SuperSightings_DaoTest file as: ```SuperSightings_Dao dao;```

Comment: I am looking into the .toString() option for analyzing, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your assistance! I was able to convert my org and fromDao objects to string to see them in the test window. The problem was with my Mapper method for the Organization object. See original and the fix below:

**Original Version**

```
    private static final class OrgMapper implements RowMapper<Organization> {
        
        @Override
        public Organization mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            Organization org = new Organization();
            org.setOrgId(rs.getInt("org_id"));
            org.setOrgName(rs.getString("org_name"));
            org.setOrgDescription(rs.getString("org_description"));
            org.setOrgPhone(rs.getString("org_phone"));
            org.setOrgEmail(rs.getString("org_street_address")); //wrong field
            org.setOrgCity(rs.getString("org_city"));
            org.setOrgState(rs.getString("org_state"));
            org.setOrgZipCode(rs.getString("org_zip_code"));
            
            return org;
        
        }    
    }
```

**Fixed OrgMapper:**

```
    private static final class OrgMapper implements RowMapper<Organization> {
        
        @Override
        public Organization mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            Organization org = new Organization();
            org.setOrgId(rs.getInt("org_id"));
            org.setOrgName(rs.getString("org_name"));
            org.setOrgDescription(rs.getString("org_description"));
            org.setOrgPhone(rs.getString("org_phone"));
            org.setOrgEmail(rs.getString("org_email"));
            org.setOrgStreetAddress(rs.getString("org_street_address"));
            org.setOrgCity(rs.getString("org_city"));
            org.setOrgState(rs.getString("org_state"));
            org.setOrgZipCode(rs.getString("org_zip_code"));
            
            return org;
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems some fields are not equal. try to compare all fields one by one to identify non-equal fields: assertEquals(fromDao.getOrgId(), org.getOrgId() and all the rest of organization's fields)